# Center Everything

Tags: css, center, centering

I am making this project in which I want all the content to me centered in the middle of the page, I can't seem to make `margin: 0px auto;` work, can anyone help me out?

(example code:)

```
<div class="barra2">
    <img src="barra2/botao_series_rotax.png">
    <img src="barra2/botao_trofeu_rotax.png">
    <img src="barra2/bot_inscricpion.jpg"> 
    <img src="barra2/bot_class_online.jpg" >
    <img src="barra2/resultados_.png">
</div>
```

(getting that centered)

Here is the fiddle of the whole thing

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/angus/b4ynL/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your only want to center the images

```
<div class="barra2">
    <img src="barra2/botao_series_rotax.png">
    <img src="barra2/botao_trofeu_rotax.png">
    <img src="barra2/bot_inscricpion.jpg"> 
    <img src="barra2/bot_class_online.jpg" >
    <img src="barra2/resultados_.png">
</div>

.barra2{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}

 .barra2 img{
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    margin:10px auto;
 }
```

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/favc2/1/)

[image]

Update:

```
.barra2{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}

 .barra2 img{
    display:inline-block;
 }
```

## [JSFIDDLE DEMO INLINE](http://jsfiddle.net/favc2/2/embedded/result/)

wenn you add width to your image you have it like this

```
.barra2{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}

 .barra2 img{
    display:inline-block;
    width:140px;
 }
```

## [DEMO INLINE-BLOCK 2](http://jsfiddle.net/favc2/3/)

[image]

For your website add this

```
.barra2 {
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
clear: both;/*this will solve the problem*/
}
```

Comment: but i want them horizontal

Comment: then display:inline-block; or float:left on img

Comment: interfers with the menu

Comment: can you show me your webapp/ webpage? if you don't want then add margin-bottom to the menu or a clear-fix

Comment: can you check the website now? how do i center my footer?

Comment: sorry i was solving an other problem yes are you there?

Answer (score 1):

`margin:0 auto` wont work unless the parent container has `text-align:center;` set, try adding the below to your CSS:

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}
```

In addition, centered content will either need to have a set width, or be set to `display:inline-block;`

Comment: Isn't it because there is no width set that `margin: 0 auto` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
div.barra2
{
text-align:center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in one div, give the div margin: auto; in the css

Like this:

```
div .everything {
      margin: auto;
      width: 1000px; /*You need to give a width, this can be 99% or 
something like this i.e. If you don't do this it won't work. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put centre tags around your code, better be best way to do it but it works

Your code between centre tags